# Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string When fetching a SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to prepare, execute, fetch into my members table. But every time I tried to fetch the SQL statement I get a error.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include('../database.php');
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($login == '') {
  $errmsg_arr[] = "Username's missing";
  $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
  $errmsg_arr[] = "Password's missing";
  $errflag = true;
}
if($errflag==true) {
  $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
  //header("Location: ../index.php");
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE login=:login && passwd=:passwd';
$login = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$pass = hash('sha1',$password,TRUE);
$arr = array(':login' => $login, ':passwd' => $pass);
$login->execute($arr);
$member = $login->fetchAll();
if (!empty($member) ){
foreach($member as $row){echo $row['login'];$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $row['member_id'];$_SESSION['username'] = $row['login'];$_SESSION['password'] = $row['passwd'];}
} else {
echo "Error.";
}
//header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

Full error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/login/login-exec.php on line 22 Call Stack: 0.0002 341584 1. {main}() /var/www/html/login/login-exec.php:0 0.0007 344512 2. PDOStatement->execute() /var/www/html/login/login-exec.php:22
```

Line 22:

```
$member = $login->fetchAll();
```

**EDIT** Here is the new code after trying everything below

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE login=:login AND passwd=:passwd';
$login = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$pass = hash('sha1',$password,TRUE);
$arr = array(':login' => $_POST['login'], ':passwd' => $pass);
$login->execute($arr);
var_dump($login);
$member = $login->fetchAll();
print_r($member);
```

New Error:

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(59) "SELECT * FROM members WHERE login=:login AND passwd=:passwd" }
```

Comment: `$fetch = $login->execute($arr);
$member = $fetch->fetchAll();`

Comment: @php NoOb I've tried this and I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what you are trying to do.

```
$login = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$pass = hash('sha1',$password,TRUE);
$arr = array(':login' => $login, ':passwd' => $pass);
```

`$login` is a PDOStatement which you just prepared. Why are you passing it to the params of the statement? Change your array assignment to

```
$arr = array(':login' => $_POST['login'], ':passwd' => $pass);
```

**EDIT:** You also seem to have a small error in your query. Change the `&&` to `AND`

Comment: That got rid of the error but it isn't fetching anything from the database.

Comment: Changed it and still nothing.

Comment: You'll also need to take php noob's suggestion.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /var/www/html/login/login-exec.php on line 24 Call Stack: 0.0000 331788 1. {main}() /var/www/html/login/login-exec.php:0 After added what php noOb said again

Comment: Actually scratch that advice. Just do one thing. after your execute(), type in this line. `var_dump($login);`